# Oracle 10 g - Setting up ODBC Connections and what is TNSNames.ora

Tags: oracle10g, odbc

I do not understand how Oracle works. This is my first tryst with Oracle, so please accept my apologies if this questions sounds silly or even ridiculously silly.

The Oracle DBA team creates a database or a schema (what is the difference?). Let us call it SIT_Release2. I am to setup the ODBC connections for it. I have some file called TNSNames.ora which resides in ORACLE_HOME\Network\Admin path.

The TNSNames.ora has the following information

SIT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "IPAddress")(PORT = 1875))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = "sit")
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )

Now, the ODBC Connection that already exists for a different database or schema (Name of it is SIT_Release1) is as below. [image]

The Data Source Name is populated with a certain value.

The Description is populated with a certain value.

The TNS Service Name is populated with value of SIT

The User Id is populated.

**Question**

The TNSNames.ora just specifies to which server I am connecting and listening via which port.

Where exactly are we specifying that this ODBC connection points to this particular database?

**EDIT**

**ANSWER**

I still do NOT understand how it works. But this is what happened -

The SID="sit" still remains as such, but the credentials I give point it to different databases.

So, in the above screenshot, the TNS Service Name is still the same. However, the username/password is different and I am able to connect to a different database.

Answer (score 0):

Its the `SID="sit"` part that points to your database.

The Oracle System ID (SID) is used to uniquely identify a particular database on a system.

For this reason, one cannot have more than one database with the same SID on a computer system

Refer [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID) or [here](http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/644749-explain-sid-tns-names) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks! "sit" is the name of the database that resides on an instance which was installed on "IPAddress" . Am I correct? Second of all, if I have two databases let us call them "sit1" and "sit1" (Yes, you read that right "sit1" is the name of the database). installed on two different servers with "IPAddress1" and "IPAddress2" then can we have the TNS Entry as follows in the same TNSNames.ora twice with just changing the IP? 
SIT = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "IPAddress2")(PORT = 1875)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = "sit1") (SERVER = DEDICATED) ) )